# npm run android commad gives cannot find symbol errors

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

While I was able to create my app with CRNA and eject it with npm run eject, and run it with npm run android, after three weeks this happened. For last 20 hours I deleted node,android studio,android sdk and downloaded all of them again. Still same errors occur. I quite do not understand if these are occur because of gradle or java or android. I have two questions.

#### Questions

1.How can I solve this problem?

2.

a) crna myApp -> cd myApp -> npm run eject -> npm run android |

b) react-native init myApp -> cd myApp -> react-native run-android

Second one works good, but I do not like expo. It seems ıt compiles and runs more slowly and creates a lot of errors with react-native link. I want to know in which circumstances I have to use one of them relatedly. I am about to kill myself so any help will be appreciated with best.

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                     ^
symbol:   class ReactApplication
location: package com.facebook.react

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
                     ^
symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
location: package com.facebook.react

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication 
{
                                                        ^
symbol: class ReactApplication

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
            ^
symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
location: class MainApplication

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
     ^
symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
location: class MainApplication

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
   ^
\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                                                   ^
symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
location: class MainApplication

\android\app\src\main\java\com\biktim\MainApplication.java:35: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
 @Override
  ^
8 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

#### MainApplication.java

```
 package com.biktim;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.biktim;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

/**
 * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
 * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
 */
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "biktim";
}
```

}

#### android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile



project.ext.react = [
   entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
* Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
*   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
*   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
* The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
* Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
* the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
*/
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
* Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
*/
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.biktim2"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + 
defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat- 
 v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "biktim2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your android/build.gradle file code, just want to confirm whether you have maven related changes.

Comment: @Sandy updated. Added build.gradle as well. Maven url directory is correct I think. I saw a lot of solutions related to maven. But my build.gradle is the  same with solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your react-native version in package.json and android/app/build.gradle.

Comment: I have updated the question. Added package.json and android/app/build.gradle. I have no idea how can I find RN version in build.gradle. Can you please check the file above and if you have any idea it woudl be apreciated.

Comment: Change implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  to implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.1"

Comment: Thank You so much. I forgot to reply but your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried all this but this error occurred now.
Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installStageDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileStageDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:stageDebugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.70.5-0.70.5.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find react-native-0.70.5-0.70.5.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5).
> Searched in the following locations:
> file:/home/abs-lt-567/Desktop/TonalProject/unison-appcode/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.70.5/react-native-0.70.5-0.70.5.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)